# How many providers can I use in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I would like to know if I can have a divider of the global state in some routes of the main content and form another global state in another route in react

**main path**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { mainStore } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "boxicons";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={mainStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

I would like to know if I can do this in some routes

```
import Header from "../../screens/user/profile/Header"; // Image of profile, information etc
import Handlers from "../../screens/user/profile/Handlers"; // Is suspended, pending money, etc
import DaysInProfile from "../../components/DaysInProfile"; // days avilable
import Filter from "../../screens/user/profile/Filter"; // Create products, send quote, or phone number. (BUTTONS)
import Products from "../../screens/user/profile/Products"; // Main content
import Advertising from "../../screens/user/profile/Advertising"; // Extra information

import ProfileController from "../../controllers/Profile"; // load information

import { profileStore } from "../../app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

function Profile() {
  return (
    <Provider store={profileStore}> // I want to know if I can have 2 global states in one route
      <ProfileController>
        <div className="profile-container">
          <Header />
          <Handlers />
          <DaysInProfile mobile />
          <div className="profile-development-container">
            <Filter />
            <Products />
            <Advertising />
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProfileController>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

I tried it but it didn't work for me, now neither the state that it creates nor the main state is useful

Comment: I don't see any reason why you should use multiple redux stores. Generally, a single redux store is enough. You can split multiple state slices for different views. See https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself

Comment: actually valid reasons to have multiple soteres are provided in the very documentaion you have linked @slideshowp2... but still it is not recommended way to go.